# In VSCode I get multiple of same file

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image: vscode]

When using VSCode...I get multiple copies of the same file opened.  The only difference between the two is that one says 'Modified' in the tooltip.  Even more troubling...I can create breakpoints in one of them and they will be completely ignored (fun!).

This has been driving me batty and my google-fu is failing me in regards to this...

Ver. 1.83.1
Win 2019 DC
PS 7.3.9

Comment: are you absolutely sure the paths are the same, the tab text suggests not, use **Copy Path** from the tab context menu and put both in a file

Comment: when is the copy opened? how many copies are possible to get opened? does this happen when you disable all your extensions? does this only happen for powershell files? or also other language modes? what if you upgrade to VS Code 1.84?

Comment: @rioV8 -> Nice catch!  It's the same file...but not the same file.  Because this is using parallel processing (foreach-object) what I do to make it easier is just create a symlink in the modules dir so that within the scriptblocks that are running in parallel I can just do "Import-Module ....".  So one file is pointing to the link..the other directly to the file.  Weird!  If you give the answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the tab text the paths are not the same.

To investigate if the paths are absolutely the same use **Copy Path** from the tab context menu and put both in a text file to compare.